# Matrix determinant with system calls

Tags: c, system-calls

So, this is my program that calculates matrix determinant using system calls, not good at all, but, the trouble is that when i put in a number bigger than 8 for dimension of matrix, it crashes somehow and i can't figure why it keeps happening. Please, give me some ideas.

The task was to calculate determinant using multithreading. Maybe, the problem is that I exceed max threads? valgrind says that

Use --max-threads=INT to specify a larger number of threads
and rerun valgrind

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
Max number of threads is too low

**compile it with gcc -g -pthread**

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

typedef struct {
    int **matrix;
    int size;
} T_MS;


void* determinant(void *npt) {
    T_MS* tmp = (T_MS*) npt;
    int i,j;
    double det = 0;
    pthread_t *array = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * tmp->size);
    T_MS   *mtarr = malloc(sizeof(T_MS)   * tmp->size);

    if (tmp->size == 1) {
        det = tmp->matrix[0][0];
    } else if (tmp->size == 2) {
        det = tmp->matrix[0][0] * tmp->matrix[1][1] - tmp->matrix[0][1] * tmp->matrix[1][0];
    } else {

        for (i = 0; i < tmp->size; ++i) {
            mtarr[i].matrix = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * tmp->size);
            mtarr[i].size = tmp->size - 1;

            for (j = 0; j < tmp->size - 1; ++j) {
                if (j < i)
                    mtarr[i].matrix[j] = tmp->matrix[j];
                else
                    mtarr[i].matrix[j] = tmp->matrix[j + 1];
            }

            pthread_create(&array[i], NULL, determinant, mtarr + i);

        }

        for (i = 0; i < tmp->size; ++i) {
            void *res;
            for (j = 0; j < tmp->size - 1; ++j) {
            }
            pthread_join(array[i], &res);
            double x = *(double *)&res;
            det += (-1 + 2 * !(i % 2)) * x * tmp->matrix[i][tmp->size - 1];


            double answer = *(double*)&det;
            free(mtarr[i].matrix);
        }


    }
    free(mtarr);
    free(array);

    void* ans = *(void **)&det;
    return ans;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int **matrix;
    int n = 0;
    int a;

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    printf("Insert the demention of matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    matrix = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));


    printf("Insert matrix:\n");


    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j]=rand()%15;
            //matrix[i][j] = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    T_MS* npt = (T_MS*)malloc(sizeof(T_MS));
    npt->matrix = matrix;
    npt->size = n;

    void *det;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, determinant, npt);
    pthread_join(tid, &det);

    double answer = *(double*)&det;
    printf("Det is: %f\n", answer);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
    free(npt);

    return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: "System calls"? What system calls?

Comment: Which exact line of code triggers the crash? A debugger can tell you that almost immediately and is the minimum info that you should collect. Also use the debugger to examine variables such as indices at the crash point, etc. That is, use standard debugging techniques.

Comment: If you're recursively creating threads you may create more than the maximum.